# maya. is there a way to activate a script job by change of viewport?

Tags: python, events, actionscript, viewport, maya

there is a event called 'ActiveViewChanged', but it doesn’t work. i would know a alternative method to launch a action just by switching viewport in maya. example:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds 
def clix():
    print "you have clicked on another view" 
cmds.scriptJob (event=["ActiveViewChanged","clix()"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that `"ActiveViewChanged"` doesn't seem to have any effect. After searching around it seems like many others have the same issue.

You can try to use this instead:
`cmds.scriptJob(event=["ModelPanelSetFocus", "clix()"])`

Though it doesn't seem to trigger when you would expect it (clicking a viewport!) Instead it triggers on key press in a viewport.

It's possible adding callbacks through the api, with `OpenMaya`. The only one I found was this:

`OpenMaya.MEventMessage.addEventCallback("ActiveViewChanged", clix)`

Though this has the exact same behavior as `"ModelPanelSetFocus"`.

I suppose you could also setup a timer that query's the current panel to detect if it has been changed or not, then trigger if it has. This could be ok for a temporary timer, like if it's for the duration of a tool being open, but I would be against it if it's suppose to run throughout the whole Maya session as it would be adding extra overhead.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the 'ActiveViewChanged' doesn't work even with the openmaya library. the event 'ModelPanelSetFocus' need the user change the focus or camera parameters. and the cameras in my scene are locked. there is only left of the temporarry timer. I have tried one. but my script kept me from working until it was finished.

Comment: 'ModelPanelSetFocus' always triggered whenever I had a viewport focused and pressed a button on the keyboard. It also triggered when pressing some buttons from the viewport's panel. Probably not what you want though.

Comment: Yes i saw it. I just want to to do the most 'user friendly' script as possible. I was hoping that a window would update just by clicking on the window. but your solution is very good, i will use it. and continuing to hope that autodesk updates the ActiveViewChanged event. thanks again.

Comment: Would be nice to get more context on what you're planning to actually do. If this is a one time operation where the user picks a viewport you can also try to use `cmds.popupMenu` so that it triggers on click.

Answer (score 0):

finally I use the ModelPanelSetFocus. In fact I can't work without the keyboard :)

```
try:
    lastActiveView
except NameError:
    global lastActiveView
    lastActiveView = None

def AVC():
    global lastActiveView
    if lastActiveView == None:
        lastActiveView = cmds.lookThru(q=True)
    if lastActiveView == cmds.lookThru(q=True):
        pass
    else:
        lastActiveView = cmds.lookThru(q=True)
        print "the view has changed ..."
jobAVC = cmds.scriptJob(e=('ModelPanelSetFocus', AVC))
```